# Table summary for sklearn classification report

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have quite a few model classification reports which I  developed using sklearn

```
===== SGD_TWEETEVAL=====

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Negative       0.64      0.56      0.60      1010
     Neutral       0.62      0.73      0.67      1476
    Positive       0.64      0.49      0.55       584

    accuracy                           0.63      3070
   macro avg       0.63      0.59      0.61      3070
weighted avg       0.63      0.63      0.63      3070

=====LINEAR SVC_TWEETEVAL=====

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Negative       0.62      0.59      0.60      1010
     Neutral       0.62      0.68      0.65      1476
    Positive       0.61      0.52      0.56       584

    accuracy                           0.62      3070
   macro avg       0.62      0.60      0.60      3070
weighted avg       0.62      0.62      0.62      3070

=====Bernoulli NB_TWEETEVAL=====

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Negative       0.63      0.64      0.63      1010
     Neutral       0.64      0.62      0.63      1476
    Positive       0.54      0.56      0.55       584

    accuracy                           0.62      3070
   macro avg       0.60      0.61      0.60      3070
weighted avg       0.62      0.62      0.62      3070

=====Multinominal NB_TWEETEVAL=====

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

    Negative       0.65      0.57      0.60      1010
     Neutral       0.61      0.74      0.67      1476
    Positive       0.63      0.42      0.51       584

    accuracy                           0.62      3070
   macro avg       0.63      0.58      0.59      3070
weighted avg       0.63      0.62      0.62      3070
```

I would like to summaries them in a table like the following:

[image: Here]

I could do it myself using LaTeX, but I am wondering if there is a quicker way to do so. `sklearn` does not seem to provide a table functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[`sklearn.metrics.classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) takes the argument `output_dict`. If you write `output_dict=True`, the result will not be a string table, but will instead be a dictionary. You can easily call `pd.DataFrame` on the resulting dictionary and manipulate / concatenate dataframes until you have your desired format. Then, use the `.to_latex` functionality of `pd.DataFrame`s.